# How to push a UIViewController on top of UINavigationController (instead of inside it)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

What I mean by this is that I have the following design of view controllers, basically in the view stack, with the app root view being on the bottom

```
UINavigationController (RootViewController -> SecondViewController)
UIViewController
AppRootViewController
```

I want to perform an action in my `SecondViewController` that is inside of the `UINavigationController`, and when I do that, I want to segue to a `NewUIViewController`, to basically result in the following view controller stack:

```
NewUIViewController
UINavigationController (RootViewController -> SecondViewController)
UIViewController
AppRootViewController
```

But what is happening is the following:

```
UINavigationController (RootViewController -> SecondViewController -> NewUIViewController)
UIViewController
AppRootViewController
```

So I'm wondering if there is any way to basically "push" a new view on top of the `UINavigationController`, instead of pushing it into the `UINavigationController`.

Right now I am doing a segue from the `SecondViewController` to the `NewUIViewController`, but perhaps I have to do the segue from the `UINavigationController` instead?  I thought I had tried this and it did not work as expected though, which is why I am asking here for some guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean present modally? how are you currently presenting the navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your segue then change "Style" to "Modal" instead of "Push". It will do the trick. But if you want to comeback to your current UINavigationController, from your new UIViewController, you must have a button to close that modal and comeback to your current UINavigationViewController.

Comment: Okay thanks I will give this a try later this evening when I am home.  I thought I have tried this before and when I went "back" to the UINavigationController, and it was showing the SecondViewController, the navigation bar acted as if I had pushed it into the UINavigationController, and there was this phantom "Back" button in the navBar, that I would have to press in order to get it to the place I left off when segueing into the NewUIViewController.

Comment: Okay so I tried this (and actually already had it this way) but it appears my problem had to do with the modal that was overtop of the navigation controller.  So I handled removing that properly when opening the next view, and it is working as expected.  I'll mark this as the correct answer though since it is the correct answer to my issue.